# Attempting to disable all links temporarily when one linked pressed using if statement (i.e. if div between left:650px and 0px, disable all links)

Tags: jquery, css, syntax, hyperlink, onclick

I am trying to state the following in jQuery: If any of 'LinkedDiv1' or 'LinkedDiv2' or 'LinkedDiv3' or 'LinkedDiv4' are between left:0 and left:650, then all links ('Link1', 'Link2', 'Link3', and 'Link4') should be off.

This is so that once I press any one link I cannot then activate another link at the same time. As each link causes a div to move from the right (left:650px) and on to the screen (left:0px); the idea is that if any LinkedDiv is not 650px or 0px then that is because it must be moving and therefore have been activated by the relevant link.

I have tried the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
if (!$('#linkedDiv1').css('left') == '0px' && !$('#linkedDiv1').css('left') == '650px'){
    $(".links").off('click'); 
    } 

else if (!$('#linkedDiv2').css('left') == '0px' && !$('#linkedDiv2').css('left') == '650px'){
    $(".links").off('click'); 
    } 

else if (!$('#linkedDiv3').css('left') == '0px' && !$('#linkedDiv3').css('left') == '650px'){
    $(".links").off('click'); 
    } 

else if (!$('#linkedDiv4').css('left') == '0px' && !$('#LinkedDiv4').css('left') == '650px'){
    $(".links").off('click'); 
    }
```

Here is a fiddle with the code (LinkedDiv1 corresponds to #rightContentService; LinkedDiv2 to #rightContentSweaters; LinkedDiv3 to #rightContentContact; LinkedDiv4 to #rightContentSeamstress) -

Full screen: https://jsfiddle.net/8eah0fvm/1/embedded/result/
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8eah0fvm/1/

Although any better solutions to my problem (at the moment I can press more than one link at a time) of deactivating temporarily the other links is preferable; it would also be interesting to see why my proposed solution did not work.

Comment: I would use a callback function with the `animate()` method to handle the links instead of checking the elements _left_ value. See the `start`, `complete` and `done` options` for [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also reduced your function down to a single reusable function but it requires adding some data attributes to your navigation element and classes to your content containers. By unbinding and rebinding the click event handlers you can avoid clicking during animation causing issues. https://jsfiddle.net/8eah0fvm/4/

HTML:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="leftMenuBar">
            <div id="leftLogo">
                <p>
                    </br>MENDICATION CORPORATION</p>
                <p id="smallerText">Mendicants of fashion</p>
            </div>
            <div class="break"></div>
            <div id="leftLinks">
                <ul>
                    <li id="linkService" data-show="rightContentService" class="links">the SERVICE</li>
                    <li id="linkSweaters" data-show="rightContentSweaters" class="links">the SWEATERS</li>
                    <li id="linkSeamstress" data-show="rightContentSeamstress" class="links">the SEAMSTRESS</li>
                    <li id="linkContact" data-show="rightContentContact" class="links">CONTACT</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="leftSpace"></div>
            <div id="leftCopyrightAndSocialMedia"></div>
        </div>


        <div id="rightContent">



            <div id="rightContentService" class="content-box">
            <h1>the SERVICE</h1>    
            </div>

            <div id="rightContentSweaters" class="content-box">
                <h1>the SWEATERS</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="rightContentSeamstress" class="content-box">
                <h1>the SEAMSTRESS</h1>
                </div>

            <div id="rightContentContact" class="content-box">
                <h1>CONTACT</h1>
                </div>


        </div>

    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#leftLinks li").bind('click', this, changeContent);
});

function changeContent(el){
    $("#leftLinks li").unbind('click', changeContent);
    var id = $(this).data('show');
    var $elem = $('#' + id);
    var shown = $('.content-box').filter(function(i, el){
        return $(el).position().left < 650;
    })[0];
    $(shown).animate({ left: "650px"}, 1000);
    $elem.delay(1000).animate({ left: '0px'}, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#leftLinks li').bind('click', this, changeContent)}, 2000); ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing to single `click` handler , using selector `$("li[id]")` , `.is()` with `:animated` selector to call `.animate()` if `div` element with `id` beginning with `"rightContent"` is not currently being animated

```
  $("li[id]").click(function () {
    var id = this.id.replace(/link/, "")
    , elems = $("div[id^=rightContent]");
    if (!elems.is(":animated")) {
        elems
        .filter(function (i, el) {
          return $(el).css("left") === "0px" && !new RegExp(id).test(el.id)
        })
        .animate({
          left: 650
        }, 1000)
        .siblings("[id$=" + id + "]")
        .delay(1000)
        .animate({
          left: "0px",
        }, 1000)
    }
  })
```

jsfiddle without `.delay(1000)` https://jsfiddle.net/8eah0fvm/5/  , https://jsfiddle.net/8eah0fvm/5/embedded/result/

with `.delay(1000)` https://jsfiddle.net/8eah0fvm/6/